# When is ReleaseController method called?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, controllers

I'm implementing a custom ASP.NET MVC controller factory.

I wonder when the `ReleaseController` method is called? Is it the same time as `EndRequest`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happens when 
`EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)` method of `MvcHandler` class is called.

asyncResult contains delegate wich been prepared by

```
IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
```

method of same class wich contains  `factory.ReleaseController(...);` call.

This is happens before Application_EndRequest (in Global.asax) is called.